# Adding a svn:// repository to Bamboo 3

Tags: svn, bamboo

I'm trying to add a svn repository using the svn:// protocol to Atlassian Bamboo 3.4.  I'm getting the following error:

> Error encountered while triggering manual build: Build '(build name)'
>   failed to check SVN repository
>
> Plan '(plan name)' did not start

Are svn:// urls unsupported in this older version of Bamboo?

Comment: Hi, did you find anything about this? I am having the same problem and am short of writing a support ticket.

Comment: I've tabled it for now.

Comment: I can't recall how I addressed the issue; it may have been a mismatch between client and server versions, but I avoided the issue for a while; hopefully I will get back to it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I have just received an answer from Atlassian in this regard. svn:// is *not* possible, only http:// or https:// and those are restricted to ports 80 and 443. I am using Bamboo OnDemand which is probably the most recent version.

It probably won't help, but at least you know what you're up to.